# Print Rails Engine Version Number in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines

I've been manually updating a Rails Engine version number in the engines footer view.

The version file is in the standard lib/ENGINENAME/version.rb folder is there a way I can get the engine's footer view to print out the engine's version number so I don't have to manually update it all the time?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is very dependent on the design of the that file but usually something as simple as `EngIneName::Version::VERSION` or `EngineName.version` will do. For Example rails is `Rails.gem_version` or `Rails::VERSION::STRING` [Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/version.rb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to show my own rails version on my website because of reasons, so I can help you with that. All you need to do is to write the following:

```
<%= Gem.loaded_specs["rails"].version.to_s %>
```

this will print you something like `5.1.1`.

Comment: You could also just use `Rails::VERSION::STRING` instead of running through `loaded_specs`

Comment: I had problems with the above methods once the engine was mounted within an app. This got me around the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this snippet of code thanks to the provided information in the comments under my question.

```
 Enginename::VERSION
```